# How to using FCMPlugin in angularjs

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

- I have using **cordova-plugin-fcm**
  https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm in my project.

  - It build on android project sucess.
  - But i don't know using FCMPlugin in code angularjs
    [image]
  - Help me

Comment: try removing `FCMPluginProvider` from controller.

Comment: @HardikVaghani thanks. i soved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at plugin site and error that you are encountering it can be said that `FCMPluginProvider` is causing the problem. From [Plugin site](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) it can be known that you don't require `FCMPluginProvider` dependency.

Regards.